# Is <span style=...> safe for sanitize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sanitize, html-safe

I am using a rich text editor (CKEditor) and I have the opportunity to let users create profiles that are displayed to other users.

Many of the attributes CKEditor can control are being lost when I display them as:

```
<%= sanitize(profile.body) %>
```

My question is: is it safe to allow the attribute 'style' to be parsed? This would allow things like text color, size, background color, centering, indenting, etc. to be displayed. I just want to be sure it won't allow a hacker access to something I don't know about!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> is it safe to allow the attribute 'style' to be parsed?

No.

```
background-image: url(javascript:[code]);
width: expression([code]);                  /* ie */
behavior: url([link to code]);              /* ie */
-moz-binding: url([link to code]);          /* ff */
```

Not to mention UI-spoofing attacks like positioning a false login form over a real one or something.

Comment: ha! Thanks very much, I had a feeling :)

Comment: See also [CSS Injection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#css-injection)

Comment: This again shows that you cannot be safe with blacklisting. If you had not thought about blacklisting url rules in CSS you would have a problem now. You cannot even output a CSS string, you really need to fully parse it and only output the parsed DOM.

Comment: but doesn't sanitize() use whitelisting?

Comment: sanitize seems to filter these examples with `:attributes => %w( style )`